# Is it safe to convert the charset of a TEXT column from utf8 to utf8mb4 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, emoji, utf8mb4

I am trying to convert the charset of a TEXT column in a huge production database from utf8 to utf8mb4 to support emojis.

I have read that for varchar columns we need to calculate and provide a different size in the alter command. But I couldn't find anything about TEXT columns.

TEXT columns are stored off the table so can I go ahead with the alter command or is there anything to be considered?

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem.

The "different size" may refer to changing `VARCHAR(255)` to `VARCHAR(191)` to fit within the 767 *byte* limit for indexes.  That is not relevant for `TEXT`.

How ere you planning on doing the conversion?  I think (but have not tested) this will work:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```